# screenshot() gives :ImportError: cannot import name glReadPixels error in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

To take a screenshot of a window in kivy we can use screenshot(name='screenshot{:04d}.png') as per the documentation

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=screenshot#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.screenshot

However i get following error when i try it :

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/Paarth/Google_Drive/Google Drive/Codes/Python/Work/kivy/kivyBasics/Screenshots_SaveImage.py", line 26, in 
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\kivy\app.py", line 766, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "D:/Paarth/Google_Drive/Google Drive/Codes/Python/Work/kivy/kivyBasics/Screenshots_SaveImage.py", line 19, in build
     Window.screenshot(name='screenshot{:04d}.png')
   File "C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 250, in screenshot
     from kivy.core.gl import glReadPixels, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
 ImportError: cannot import name glReadPixels

Code used :

```
import  kivy
kivy.require ( '1.8.0 ' )
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import WindowBase
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = MyWidget()

        a = Button(text="hello")
        parent.add_widget(a)
        Window.screenshot(name='screenshot{:04d}.png')

        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: How did you install kivy? Did you download the distribution zip? And is this windows 7?

Comment: yes download the zip and yes its windows 7 .

Comment: How did you run it? Did you run it from the kivy provided kivy.bat file? If not, try to run it from there and see if you get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the answer by inclement, you need to do the following, with the export_to_png included in your python file. This

```
from kivy.graphics import Canvas, Translate, Fbo, ClearColor, ClearBuffers
kv = '''
cameraWidget:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: "Take picture"
        on_press: root.TakePicture()
        height: '48dp'

'''
class cameraWidget(BoxLayout):
    def TakePicture(self, *args):
        self.export_to_png = export_to_png
        self.export_to_png(self.ids.camera, filename='test2.png')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find `glReadPixels` in `kivy.graphics.opengl`.
Try the following in Python interpreter:

```
>>> from kivy.graphics.opengl import glReadPixels
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, I've reported an issue about it.

In the meantime (and related to your earlier question), you could use the new `export_to_png` method of Widget by just copying its code into your own widget, you can find the code [on github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L528).

Comment: ok .. Thanks for raising the bug and taking the code of export_to_png in my function works